# Veryfing fingerprints using SharpSSH while connecting to SFTP Server

Tags: ssh, sftp, public-key, sharpssh, rsa-key-fingerprint

I am using `Tamir.SharpSSH` to make `SFTP` connections in my `.NET` code. I have servers' host, port, username, password and servers' fingerprint.

I am able to connect to the server without the fingerprint. Is there any way to match the fingerprint that I have with the servers' before making the connection?

Following is my `C#` code for the connection:

```csharp
string _ftpURL = "ftp.com"; //Host URL or address of the SFTP server
string _UserName = "Login_Id";      //User Name of the SFTP server
string _Password = "12345";   //Password of the SFTP server
int _Port = 22;                  //Port No of the SFTP server (if any)
string _ftpDirectory = "ReceivedFiles"; //The directory in SFTP server where the files will be uploaded
string LocalDirectory = "D:\\FilePuller"; //Local directory from where the files will be uploaded

ArrayList UploadedFiles = new ArrayList();

Sftp oSftp = new Sftp(_ftpURL, _UserName, _Password);

oSftp.Connect(_Port);
```

Is there anyway I can add a check for Server's fingerprint before connecting to the `SFTP` Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharpSSH is stupid enough not to verify the host keys by default.

You would have to re-implement `SshBase.ConnectSession` not to set `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`.

- And then use `JSch.getHostKeyRepository().add()` to configure expected host key (or implement `HostKeyRepository` interface).
- Or implement `UserInfo` interface, particularly the `promptYesNo` method.

Comment: HI, Thanks for your help. I have set the StrictHostKeyChecking property to yes, but could you please elaborate on the next step (any sample code). This is how i have set StrictHostKeyChecking property.  Code : 
             Hashtable config = new Hashtable();
            config.Add("StrictHostKeyChecking", "yes");

Comment: Hi Martin,
I was going through the forums and like you many others suggested to go for Known_Hosts implementation.However i am confused as to where should that file (known_hosts) be placed as i could not locate the path ~/.ssh/known_hosts. i am working on a windows machine and using .net code. Can you please help me with the implementation of known_hosts.

Comment: I do not suggest `known_hosts` implementation. I believe that `JSch.getHostKeyRepository().add()` is the simplest and most straightforward solution.

Comment: Do u have any sample code? I am a complete newbie to sFTP..  ;-(

Comment: Martin can you please provide some inputs. i have implemented  myJsch.getHostKeyRepository().add and its still throwing "reject hostkey exception"

 UserInfo ui=new MyUserInfo();
 mySession.setUserInfo(ui);

myJsch.getHostKeyRepository().add(_ftpURL, fingerPrint_bytes, ui);

Q1)  In this is the fingerprint supposed to be converted in bytes?
Q2) What all should be there in the "ui" object.

Comment: Hey... Just got done with this... :-) All thanks to u Martin...  a small eureka moment for me.. :-p

Comment: A small question.. in this implementation, sharpSSH asks me whether i want to trust a particular finger print or not. Is there a way i can skip this step and accept it programmitically?  But, I do not want to set "strictHostKeyChecking" to "no". Is there any workaround.
i was thinking of adding the fingerprint in the Known_hosts file manually but I think I cannot do so as the finger prints are stored in encrypted format in known_hosts file.
Can you please suggest some work-around for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "asks me"? When does it ask you? What specifically?